# capistrano 3 set ssh port but 22 is still used

Tags: ssh, port, capistrano3

I'm trying to set up access to server via a port (ssh is on port 222), but still although i have in my `deploy.rb`

> set :application, 'billing'
>   set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:random/stat.git'
>   set :keep_releases, 5
>   set :ssh_options, {
>       forward_agent: true,
>       port: 222
>   }
>   SSHKit.config.command_map[:rake]  = "bundle exec rake" #8
>   SSHKit.config.command_map[:rails] = "bundle exec rails"

I still get error

```
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host IP:
Operation timed out - connect(2) for "IP" port 22
```

How can i solve this error? what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I was also having issues with `ssh_options` option.

I switched to using `server` method, so it looks something like this:

```
# config/deploy/production.rb
server "#{server_ip_here}", user: "deploy", roles: %w{web app db}, port: 222
```

Comment: yes, you're correct. in my case it was a server side problem. had to spend some time tweaking server

Comment: This was a lifesaver for me. For some reason the syntax above when using the role-based syntax failed but using the one-liner you listed worked.

Answer (score 2):

I also give another ans:
role :web, %w{deploy@123.456.78.9:222}